# "[Filename] is not a directory" when I try to change names en masse with mv?

Tags: 16.04, command-line

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64 bit.

I have a folder full of 44 jpeg files with the following naming format—

```
0094-001.png.jpeg
0094-002.png.jpeg
…
0094-044.png.jpeg
```

I want to change them all into files with the following naming format—

```
0094-001.jpeg
0094-002.jpeg
…
0094-044.jpeg
```

I attempt the following command in the terminal—

```
mv ./*.png.jpeg ./*.jpeg
```

I get the following error—

```
mv: target './0094-044.png.jpeg' is not a directory
```

Why?

Comment: Because `mv` simply doesn't work that way (although `mmv` does - kinda, the replacement syntax is different). It moves (renames) a single file to a single target, or moves multiple files to a single target directory.

Comment: I don't think you can use the wildcard (*) in the destination name. You will probably need to use a script to do this.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181141/rename-multiple-files-with-mv